# Poisson Distribution Problem

Tags: probability, statistics

The random variable $X$ has a Poisson distribution with mean $\mu$. Show that $$P(X \equiv 1 \bmod 2)=a+be^{c\mu}$$

where $a$, $b$, and $c$ have to be determined.

I plugged $X \equiv 1 \bmod 2$ into the Poisson distribution equation:
$$P(X=k)={\lambda^k e^k\over k!}$$ but was not really sure where to go from there.

Comment: $P(X=k)={\lambda^{k}e^{-\lambda}\over k!}$ and not ...

Comment: Hint:  write out the meaning of $X \equiv 1 \bmod 2$. Which values of $X$ satisfyes that. You will find you have to do an infinite sum problem.

Comment: You've taken the practice of making MathJax code more complicated then necessary to extremes that are more extreme than some I've seen here, at least.  But you need $\dfrac{\mu^k e^{-\mu}}{k!}$, not $\dfrac{\lambda^k e^k}{k!}$.  The quantity $e^k$ should not appear here.  I simplified the code.

Comment: Sorry, I was kind of in a hurry whilst I was typing that, but I understand the problem now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$P(X\equiv 1 \bmod 2)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}P(X=2k+1)$

Replacing $P(X=2k+1)$ by its value, you'll recognize the $\sinh$ function.

Comment: Can you further explain how the sinh appear here?

Comment: $$\sinh(\lambda)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\lambda^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$

Comment: Thx. Perheps the OP would recognize easier what you meant, now.